# What is the purpose of having a boolean expression containing an exit code in this shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I have a problem which is solved by this answer https://superuser.com/a/508761

Now I need to expand on it to do other stuff but first I need to understand better how it works before modifying it. Here's the script in question:

```
#!/bin/bash

(( $# != 2 )) && exit 1

for f in *; do
  newf="${f//$1/$2}"
  if [[ $f != $newf ]]; then
    mv "$f" "$newf"
  fi
done
```

What does `(( $# != 2 )) && exit 1` do? I've had little luck finding explanations online: I found out what each component is but not what the entire line does in the script as a whole. The answer didn't explain that line. The poster was last online over 2 years ago and I didn't want to necro a 5 year old question, so here I am.

Comment: Just a guess, but I'd assume it is checking for two arguments being passed to the script and if it does not get exactly two then it will exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It is a control operator

From *bash man*:

```
 The control operators && and || denote AND lists and OR lists, respectively.
 An AND list has the form

        command1 && command2

 command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.
 [..cut..]
 The return status of AND and OR lists is the exit status of the last command
 executed in the list.
```

A *control operator* is

```
    A token that performs a control function.  It is one of the following symbols:
        || & && ; ;; ( ) |
```

[(credits)](https://serverfault.com/a/53618/214749)

So in this case, do not read `&&` as a boolean operator.
So now you know when `exit 1` is executed – only on success of previous command (if exit status was zero).

See this [serverfault asnswer](https://serverfault.com/a/53684/214749) for **explanation of `&&` in 3 different contexts in Bash.** Useful for learning distinctions between them.

Answer (score 1):

It exits the script at that line if there weren't exactly two arguments passed to the script.

- `$#` is the number of arguments passed in when calling the script, analogous to `argc` in C
- `(( $# != 2 ))` returns with a truey code (`0`) if the number of arguments is not equal to `2`
- `&&` runs the right hand side only if the left hand side exited with a truey code. Which means the right hand side is run if the number of arguments is not 2.
- `exit 1` exits the script with the falsey exit code of `1`. This aborts the script at this point and informs the caller that there was an error.

Comment: Would make more sense to write it as `(( $# == 2 )) || exit`, which can almost be read as "assert(argc == 2)".

Comment: @grawity Eh, the `if (argc != 2) return;` construct is quite popular. `||` more naturally translates to `else`, which might seem odd to someone familiar with other languages.